# How to prevent API Gateway OAuth scope being reset upon Lambda function deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS Chalice project. The project consists of an API Gateway in front of a Lamdba function which uses Cognito for auth. For my Cognito auth to work I need my endpoints on API Gateway to have the OAuth scope shown below (`aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`).

OK, fine. The problem is, every time I make some code change to the Lambda server and re-deploy, the OAuth Scope field gets wiped on *every* endpoint. So I have to manually paste that string back in after every deploy.

Does anyone know any way to auto-fill these? I can't find anything in the Chalice docs for having this set up on deploy, nor can I find anything on the API Gateway GUI. Thanks!

How the endpoints look when properly set up:

[image: working setup]

OAuth scope reset after deploy:

[image: reset oauth scope]